# TableView doesn't allow scrolling if it contains only a few rows

Tags: ios, scroll, tableview

In my navigation controller, I have a TableView  with a searchbar at the top. I want this searchbar hidden unless the user drags the table down (as in how it works in the Music app). But if my table has only a few rows (not enough to cause content to go offscreen), the table isn't initially scrollable. If I select a row (causing the navigation controller to load a new view) and then go back to the original view, the table is now scrollable and I can drag down the table to expose to searchbar.

I have no idea what's causing this. I don't know if it's an Apple bug or if I've done something stupid in my code. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Without seeing your code I cannot decide whether your are doing something crazy in your code. I am not a wizard.

Comment: If you're using a Xib file. Select the table and examine the properties under the "Scroll View" section of the attributes inspector.

Comment: Thanks, Sanjay. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in there to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think it's a bug in iOS. After a lot of mucking around with my code, and Googling, I found someone else with the same problem:

[UITableView Won't Scroll In Certain Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522838/uitableview-wont-scroll-in-certain-conditions)

They put forward a solution that has worked for me.